# In Tampopo, who does this?

Tags: tampopo

In 1985's Tampopo, byJuzo Itami

> The **Man in a White Suit** (Kōji Yakusho) is shot several times in the chest, until he falls to his death. We never see the person holding the gun.

Is their identity revealed?

Answer (score 1):

Although I have only watched it in translation (i.e. subtitled) it is my recollection that the killer was not revealed, nor was their identity important.

The character in question's demise is a function of his criminal life and career.  Live by the gun, die by the gun.  Details irrelevant since his story arc was all about the girl and the oyster, as opposed to his career as a gangster.

Comment: What do you mean "live by the gun" - is he a gangster? (I can't recall that much being said about him)

Comment: It has been many years since I last watched this extraordinary film, so I can't give you the exact points, but it is strongly implied the character is a gangster. (Some of the clues may be cultural, but his flashy dress and lifestyle of catered dinners a the movies may be taken as indicators.)